# How to identify download in progress in chrome using selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do i identify download is not completed /in progress ? because i want to close web driver after download finished.

```
WebDriver: Chrome
```

sample code like this ,assume chrome driver setup is ready.

```
@Test
public void testDownloadPdf(){
// here is the selenium java code to download pdf.
// when do i perform driver.close();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this... it work in my case
here i'm using `FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(downloadfolder)` it will return size of directory and will check after every 5 sec is the size is equal or not.if file size is equal then download is completed .

```
private void waitForDownloadFinished() throws Exception {
            try {
                String path = "/Download/path/";
                if (path != null) {
                    File folder = new File(path);
                    long size, reSize;
                    do {
                        size = FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(folder);
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        reSize = FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(folder);
                    } while (size != reSize);
                    System.out.println("Download completed");
                }           
} catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw e;
            } finally {
                getWebBrowser().quit();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, better close the driver in `@AfterClass`.
If you know the exact file name and expected location, you can use `Paths`

```
String file_path_full = "C:\\users\\username\\downloads\\yourpdffile.pdf";
while(Files.notExists(Paths.get(file_path_full))) {Thread.sleep(10000);}
```

Comment: actually i don't know the exact file name...i'm locating that pdf file and onClick of that directly downloding is initiated...

Comment: Mocking the file object would be a solution for not knowing the file name

Comment: @Prashant Palve are you able to find out the file name from any WebElement's attribute? Or predict the file name?

Comment: @pburgr yes,i can predict the filename.

Comment: Then you can use: String file_path_full = "PREDICTED FILE LOCATION INCLUDING FILE NAME";

Comment: @pburgr, i think even file is not completely download it will show file is exist.

Comment: No it does not, I'm using it and it works just fine. Important is the sleep, it has to wait long enought. Files *.part will never fit the predicted file_path_full.